# How to clear Tetris lines in Unity game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a simple Tetris game in Unity. Everything works except I can't clear lines and I don't know why.

In my code I put in to check for completed lines. If it is a completed line it should clear the line and all the blocks should move one row down. Unfortunately, my code doesn't work.

```
public Vector3 rotationPoint;
private float previousTime;
public float fallTime = 0.8f;
public static int height = 20;
public static int width = 10;
private static Transform[,] grid = new Transform[width, height];

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
        transform.position += new Vector3 (-1, 0, 0);
        if (!ValidMove ())
            transform.position -= new Vector3 (-1, 0, 0);
    }  else if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
        transform.position += new Vector3 (1, 0, 0);
        if (!ValidMove ())
            transform.position -= new Vector3 (1, 0, 0);
    }  else if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
        transform.RotateAround (transform.TransformPoint(rotationPoint), new Vector3 (0, 0, 1), 90);
        if (!ValidMove ())
            transform.RotateAround (transform.TransformPoint(rotationPoint), new Vector3 (0, 0, 1), -90);
    }

    if (Time.time - previousTime > (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.DownArrow) ? fallTime / 10 : fallTime)) {
        transform.position += new Vector3 (0, -1, 0);
        if (!ValidMove ()){
            transform.position -= new Vector3 (0, -1, 0);
            AddToGrid ();
            this.enabled = false;
            FindObjectOfType<SpawnTetromino> ().NewTetromino ();
        }
        previousTime = Time.time; 
    }
}

void CheckForLines(){
    for (int i = height-1; i >= 0; i--){
        if(HasLine(i)){
            DeleteLine(i);
            RowDown(i);
        }
    }
}

bool HasLine(int i){
    for(int j = 0; j< width; j++){
        if(grid[j, i] == null)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void DeleteLine(int i){
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++){
        Destroy(grid[j, i].gameObject);
        grid[j, i] = null;
    }
}

void RowDown(int i){
    for (int y = i; y < height; y++){
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++){
            if(grid[j,y] != null){
                grid[j, y - 1] = grid[j,y];
                grid[j, y] = null;
                grid[j, y - 1].transform.position -= new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}


void AddToGrid(){
    foreach (Transform children in transform) {
        int roundedX = Mathf.RoundToInt (children.transform.position.x);
        int roundedY = Mathf.RoundToInt (children.transform.position.y);

        grid [roundedX, roundedY] = children;
    }
}

bool ValidMove(){
    foreach (Transform children in transform) {
        int roundedX = Mathf.RoundToInt (children.transform.position.x);
        int roundedY = Mathf.RoundToInt (children.transform.position.y);

        if (roundedX < 0 || roundedX >= width || roundedY < 0 || roundedY >= height) {
            return false;
        }
        if (grid [roundedX, roundedY] != null)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: "My code doesnt work" is not very specific unfortunately. Maybe you can give a more detailed description of what doesnt work / what you tried? Did you try to debug it yourself? Does it not compile? Does it the wrong thing? 
Right now you basically expect somebody to read your 100 lines of code and debug it for you without knowing what happens, and thats a bit much to be honest.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What Christian tried to say is: Please reduce your code and only show us what is minimal necessary to reproduce the error. E.g. we don't care what do with `GetKeyDown` if it is not related to the issue. Better tell us exactly where e.g. `CheckForLine` is called and what exactly behaves different from what you would expect to happen?

Comment: and actually for correct Tetris behaviour your code should rather check if there are 1 to 4 (a Tetris) lines that can be removed at once. It is also enough to check those lines where the last placed tile landed since those lines are the only ones changed in that step.

Answer (score -1):

Add CheckForLines() to the end of Update method. Currently you are not using it